# Opening Java's JSP Login and Registration files on Angular Project

Tags: java, angular

I'm new with Angular and I have set up my Spring Security Registration and Login Authentications on Java side + also set up Item List on Angular side. Now When I boot angular I want to see the Login/Registration Pages from JSP and when I login successfully I want to open my Angular Component. Is this possible ?

TL:DR - Is it possible to open JSP login page and after logging in , opening Angular component?

Comment: you have to redirect to jsp page and than redirect back to angular after successfull login

Comment: or implememnt login form directly in angular. its just sending 2 or 3 values after all

Comment: use response.sendRedirect("<PageName>"); method.